# .load() not working with external link

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#s").load("http://www.universalis.com/mass.htm");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="s"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

div is not loading link , it is showing blank page .
Is there any other way to load external link except iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load external link in ".load()"

create page say external.php

In external.php put following code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://ur/url/here'; 
echo $var = get_file_contents($url); ?>
```

now load this page in jquery n it will load external link

```
$('div').load('external.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Question1:** **.load() not working with external link**

**Answer1:** This is possible when both pages are on the same server.
You should take a look at `jQuery's .load()` function: http://api.jquery.com/load/

**Question2:** **Is there any other way to load external link except iframe?**
**Answer2:** Yes this is possible you can use object tag. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/APNj3/)**

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try by using this.

```
$("#s").html('<object data="http://www.universalis.com/mass.htm">');
```

It works fine.

Comment: Using an object is effectively the same as using an iframe, but with less consistency and fewer features.

Comment: But we can't load part of external page using object i guess. for example in .load() we can use :: $("#s").load("http://www.universalis.com/mass.htm #somediv");